# RegEx splitting multiple lines - grouped by ID

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would like to create a regular expression to split a CSV file into multiple files based on an ID which can be found in each row. Here is an example:

```
ID,text,value
1,some text,5
1,other text,3
1,something,2
2,sample,4
3,john doe,2
3,jane doe,3
4,foo,1
4,bar,2
4,baz,3
```

The expected capturing groups would be

```
1,some text,5
1,other text,3
1,something,2

2,sample,4

3,john doe,2
3,jane doe,3

4,foo,1
4,bar,2
4,baz,3
```

What makes it even more complicated is that the ID might appear 1 or multiple times (like 2 above).
Here is what I tried:

```
^.*?\n(((\d+),.*?\n)(\2.*?){0,})
```

But it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode to group individual blocks with same `ID`:

```sh
^(\d+).*[\r\n]+(?:\1.*[\r\n]+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y7GjE7/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture in group #1
- `.*[\r\n]+`: Match everything until end of line
- `(?:\1.*[\r\n]+)*`: Match same digit and rest of the line. Repeat this group 0 or more times

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I really have to get familiar with the non-capturing groups.
Only one thing I had to change: last line do not have linebreak so [\r\n]+ was changed to [\r\n]*